# Binding resource with Xaml x:Uid some times not working

Tags: windows-10, win-universal-app, uid, currentculture

I have an UWP app with two languages. For some labels I've used: `Loader.GetString("LableName")` in code-behind and for the others have used: `x:Uid` in XAML.
Users can change the `CurrentCulture` using a button like this:

```
 CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fa-IR");
```

For the first time totally work correct,
But for the next times, after the button is clicked, those labels that have bound in the code-behind will work properly, 
But those that have bound in the XAML with `X:Uid`, still display previous language resource strings.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Hi! Have you solved that issue?

Answer (score 1):

In `WPF` we use something like this to apply culture on window elements ([reference](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2009/Jun/14/WPF-Bindings-and-CurrentCulture-Formatting)), use it in your `UWP` app, i hope it help:

```
public MyWindow()
{    
    this.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag);
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

You can also set the language globally for your entire application in the App class:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);

    // Set application startup culture based on config settings
    string culture = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Culture"];
    SetCulture(culture);  
    FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FrameworkElement),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the button property: double click on the button, after you have to set the value of the label in the method "button_click".